# Почему куки не удаляются даже при указании прошедшего времени

Tags: php, cookie

Добоавляю куки

```
setcookie('user_uid','something',time()+(3600*24*30),'/');
```

и удаляю при кое каких условиях

```
setcookie('user_uid','',time()-(3600*24*30),'/');
```

все как бы работает ( остальной код рядом выполняется там же при этих условиях) но после перезагрузки кукисы снова есть, почему так может происходить и как решить?

Comment: пока что видно одно объяснение - когда вы перезагружаете страницу - код запроса страницы записывает куки

Comment: а нет куки записываются когда человек логинится а удаляются когда нажимает выйти, это два отдельных запроа POST и они одновременно не могут сработать